# Why is Long unable to accept 12 digit value even though I explicitly declared it to?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

            int k=s.nextInt();
            long  value=0L;

            value=(k-(k/2)) * (k/2);

            System.out.println(value);

    }
}
```

Now, I gave my input as **1856378** for **k**,
Expected output is **861534819721**
but I got **-1753606775**

Why is giving wrong answer eventhough the **value** is **long**

Comment: Replace int K for long and you will get your expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the expression

```
(k-(k/2)) * (k/2)
```

There are no `long` values involved, only `int` values. As such, no value is promoted to `int`. We simply have `int` arithmetic. You're limited with the range of `int`.

If `k` would be declared as a `long`, things would be different

```
long k = s.nextInt();
```

Similarly, you could cast or declare one of the values of the expression as a `long`.

```
value = (k - (k / 2L)) * (k / 2);
```

But this may depend on associativity and order of execution. It will work here, but not necessarily in other expressions.

Comment: so there is no relationship to the conversion of int to long which is not allowed?

Comment: @KickButtowski `int` to `long` is allowed.

Comment: oh k so the op's question is not related to casting at all?

Comment: @KickButtowski I don't think so.

Answer (score 6):

You're *assigning* to a `long`, but all the *arithmetic* is being done with `int`, because every part of the expression `(k-(k/2)) * (k/2)` is an `int`.

The simplest fix would be to declare `k` as a `long`, e.g.

```
long k = s.nextInt();
long value = (k-(k/2)) * (k/2);
```

You could alternatively use `2L` for the literal in either of the division operations - it's only the multiplication that you really need to be done using `long` arithmetic.

It's always worth bearing in mind that the calculation on the right hand side of an assignment operator is completely separate from whatever it happens to be assigned to.